# Call method from Kotlin class

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar, kotlin

I have an util Kotlin class where I set toolbar title, hide or show toolbar depends on the fragment:

```
class MyToolbarUtils() {

    fun hideToolbar(activity: Activity) {
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }

    fun showToolbar(activity: Activity, tag: String) {
        setToolbarTitle(tag, activity)
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar!!.show()
    }

    fun setToolbarTitle(tag: String, activity: Activity) {
        var title = ""
        when (tag) {
            "Main_fragment" -> title = activity.resources.getString(R.string.Main_screen)
            "Add_note" -> title = activity.resources.getString(R.string.Add_note)
        }
        activity.title = title
    }
}
```

how to call showToolbar(...) from Fragment?
I just tried `MyToolbarUtils.showToolbar(..)` but it can not be possible

only one way I discover is:

```
val setToolbarTitle = MyToolbarUtils()
setToolbarTitle.showToolbar(activity, tag)
```

but there must be better way to do that..

Comment: Does Kotlin have static methods? If not, what you've shown makes sense

Comment: If all of these only work with one class, `MainActivity` why are they just not methods on that class?

Comment: You asked an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info/) ... you decided on an answer to a programming problem and then asked for help using that pre-decided answer.  But in this case your answer is not the correct one at all.  Idiomatic Kotlin would not use statics or object declarations in a case like this, but instead use http://stackoverflow.com/a/39499145/3679676

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Convert your **class** into an **object** which is supposed to work similarly to java static methods.

You can get more info here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations

Comment: then how to call that function from fragment and adapter ??

Comment: @chandanicpatel...`Class.Method()` or using example above... `MyToolbarUtils.showToolbar()`. OP put this in his question

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like `MyToolbarUtils` should be an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions-and-declarations) instead of a class.

Another way would be to declare functions inside this class on the top level in a file (not inside any class) and just refer to them by their simple name.

Answer (score 3):

Others answered how to make your functions feel like static methods, but for this use case you have a more idiomatic option.

**Extension functions in Kotlin replace static utility classes in Java:**

Since **all** of your functions take an `Activity` as a parameter, why not use [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) and make them extend the `Activity` or `MainActivity` class instead?

```
fun MainActivity.hideToolbar() {
    supportActionBar!!.hide()
}

fun MainActivity.showToolbar(tag: String) {
    setToolbarTitle(tag)
    supportActionBar!!.show()
}

fun Activity.setToolbarTitle(tag: String) {
    title = when (tag) {
        "Main_fragment" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Main_screen)
        "Add_note" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Add_note)
        else -> "" // or did you mean this to be an exception?
    }
}
```

Now they are all in context of your `MainActivity` or `Activity` classes (the `this` is now an instance of one of those), you don't have to go hunt for them in some other unrelated `ActivityUtils` class.  Whenever you are inside the activity class you can simply:

```
showToolbar("Main_fragment")
```

or from somewhere else where you have a reference to an activity:

```
// you have a reference of MainActivity type
myMainActivity.showToolbar("Main_fragment")

// you have a reference you can cast to MainActivity type
(someActivity as MainActivity).showToolbar("Main_fragment")

// this function works with any Activity
someActivity.setToolbarTitle("Add_note")
```

Also note that I cleaned up the code a little and used [`when` as an expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) to set the title, and also the removal of `var` (it is rare when you need a `var`, so always think about how to work with `val`).   And as an expression the `when` will need an `else` clause, so I made that the same as you default `""` empty string.

**Alternative as Class Methods:**

Since all 3 methods all require an instance of `MainActivity` (based on their casting), why not just put them into `MainActivity` as member functions.

```
class MainActivity ... {
    ...

    fun hideToolbar() {
        supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }

    fun showToolbar(tag: String) {
        setToolbarTitle(tag)
        supportActionBar!!.show()
    }

    fun setToolbarTitle(tag: String) {
        title = when (tag) {
            "Main_fragment" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Main_screen)
            "Add_note" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Add_note)
            else -> "" // or did you mean this to be an exception?
        }
    }
}
```

And call them from any reference to `MainActivity`.

**Alternative as Object Declaration:**

Lastly as suggested by others and for completeness, here they are in a utility class acting similar to statics but instead methods on a singleton [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations):

```
object MyToolbarUtils() {
    fun hideToolbar(activity: MainActivity) {
        activity.supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }

    fun showToolbar(activity: MainActivity, tag: String) {
        setToolbarTitle(activity, tag)
        activity.supportActionBar!!.show()
    }

    fun setToolbarTitle(activity: Activity, tag: String) {
        activity.title = when (tag) {
            "Main_fragment" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Main_screen)
            "Add_note" -> title = resources.getString(R.string.Add_note)
            else -> "" // or did you mean this to be an exception?
        }
    }
}
```

But I think this is the worst and least Kotlin-like way to extend functionality of another class.  Classes/Objects like `SomethingUtils` full of statics means that you probably should be writing [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a singleton class in Kotlin using the object keyword and call Kotlin singleton class in Java like below :

```
object SampleSingleton {
   fun someMethod() { 
     println("I love coding")
   }
}
```

If from Java then as follows

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   SampleSingleton.INSTANCE.someMethod();
}
```

or from Kotlin class as follows

```
SampleSingleton.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this meets your definition of a better way, but a simpler way would have been to replace your two lines of code:

```
val setToolbarTitle = MyToolbarUtils()
setToolbarTitle.showToolbar(activity, tag)
```

with this single line;

```
MyToolbarUtils().showToolbar(activity, tag)
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -3):

```
// Kotlin

@file:JvmName("DemoUtils")
package demo

class ClassInKotlin

fun methodInKotlin() {
}

// Java
new demo.ClassInKotlin();
demo.DemoUtils.methodInKotlin();
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. He isn't trying to call the code from Java, nor do you need to have the `@JvmName` no the `ClassInKotlin` nor the calls from Java.