# How to run a function from one class in another class in Android Studio [Kotlin]?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to save user preferences for language, so I have a preferences class with a setter and getter for language, as well as a separate Language activity where the user actually picks which language they want.

From this language activity, I want to use the setter to set the user's chosen language preference within the preferences class. Here is the preferences class:

```
class Preferences (context: Context) {
    val PREFS_FILENAME = "artour.prefs"
    val LANGUAGE = "language"
    val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    fun getLang() : String {
        return prefs.getString(LANGUAGE, "english")
    }

    public fun setLang(lang:String) {
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putString(LANGUAGE, lang)
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

How would I go about running the setLang method from the language activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call method from Kotlin class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489887/call-method-from-kotlin-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont now if I'm missing anything in this question, but just do this:

```
val preferences = Preferences(this)
preferences.setLang("it is that easy")
```

in any function in your activity class.

What it does is create an object (`val preferences = Preferences()`) and then calling a method on it (`preferences.setLang("this is a string")`). 
Make sure to use an actual language identifier instead of a random string though.

Comment: Thanks a ton, turns out I was a little off on my syntax with it, I'm super new to kotlin. When I type the first line, it says I have to pass a parameter for context for Parameter(). Do you know what I would pass for "context"? Thanks again

Comment: A [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) see indirect subclasses -> your Activity -> inside the `Actiity`-class it is just `this`.