# How to use function in another class in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new at Kotlin.I have class and I want to call function in another class I try to use answer as in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489887/call-method-from-kotlin-class) but it gives me `expecting member declaration error`

How i can use it?

Here my class

```
class MyClass() {
 //Do stafff
 val msg="Text"

 MyObject.sendMsg("msg") //getting here error
}


//Another file i have this object file
object MyObject{
  fun sendMsg(msg:String){
    println("I get your message $msg")
  }
}
```

Comment: Function calls can only be made from within functions/constructors, or as assignments to properties. Your `MyObject.sendMsg("msg")` call is just sitting out in the open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute code just in class body. For example you can declare a method

```kotlin
class MyClass() {
    //Do stafff
    val msg="Text"

    fun test() {
        MyObject.sendMsg("msg") //getting here error
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i want to call MyClass inside test is it possible to call that also another class?

Comment: yes, you can call methods of your class from other class methods or standalone functions